# Como filtrar por componentes en Strapi

Tags: javascript, nodejs

Me gustaría saber como puedo filtar por componentes en [Strapi](https://strapi.io/):

Actualmente tengo (y funciona):

```
    entities   = await strapi.services.accommodation.find({
         name: { $regex: '(?i).*' + ctx.query._q + '.*' },
    });
```

Me gustaría poder filtrar también por el valor lat del componente address:

```
     entities   = await strapi.services.accommodation.find({
     name: { $regex: '(?i).*' + ctx.query._q + '.*' },
     address.lat: { $regex: '(?i).*' + ctx.query._lat + '.*' },
        });
```

Sin embargo, me da el siguiente error:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token '.'
    at wrapSafe (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1072:16)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1122:27)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1178:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1002:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:901:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1044:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:77:18)
    at loadFiles (/root/buscoresi/node_modules/strapi/lib/load/load-files.js:35:17)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
    at async module.exports (/root/buscoresi/node_modules/strapi/lib/core/load-apis.js:18:16)
```

**EDIT**
A fecha de 5/14/2020 no es posible hacer eso en strapi directamente, debes usar mongoose.

Comment: Hola. El idioma de este SO es español. Por favor, edita tu pregunta y tradúcela incluyendo el título.

Comment: Editado! Gracias por el aviso

Comment: Respuesta rápida, por ahora no es posible :)

Comment: Jajajaja, yo le pondría a la pregunta la versión de strapi y me respondería a mí mismo con la evidencia de por qué, al día de hoy, no se puede. COn eso, si después añaden una forma, alguien puede venir a responder (y otros sabrán que no se puede)

Comment: Que lo pongas como respuesta, no editando la pregunta! :P Es para que te la puedas aceptar a ti mismo y salga verdecita, diciendo _tiene una respuesta aceptada_

Comment: @Alfabravo Listo ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A fecha de 5/14/2020 no es posible hacer eso en strapi directamente, debes usar mongoose.